# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-timepicker

I tried all the answers to resolve this error, but it's not working.

This is my controller:

```
import_file($this->css, 
            array('colorbox.css', 
                  'jquery.timepicker.css',
                  'calender/default.css', 
                  'calender/default.time.css',
                  'calender/default.date.css', 
                  'responsive-tables.css'));

import_file($this->javascript, 
            array('jquery.colorbox.js',
                  'jquery.ui.js', 
                  'jquery.timepicker.js', 
                  'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', 
                  'responsive-tables.js',
                  'calender/picker.js',
                  'calender/picker.date.js',
                  'calender/picker.time.js', 
                  'calender/legacy.js', 
                  'calender/calender.js',
                  'scheduler.js',
                  'customer.js'));
```

This is the error part:

```
$.ui.timepicker = $.ui.timepicker || {};
if ($.ui.timepicker.version) {
    return;
}
```

Is there any other way to resolve this error?

Comment: "Is there any other way to resolve this error?" You didn't specify any way that you tried to resolve the error. What answers did you try?

Comment: import_file($this-> is not javascript or jquery related

Answer (score 1):

I did not see `jquery.min.js` file in your code. Please include jquery.min.js as the first one.

Comment: am a fresher so i dont know more,jquery.min.js means jquery-1.11.1.min.js or addon

Comment: first code is used to import the js files in my web page.

Comment: I tried after including jquery.min.js files as first but tat time also hv d same error